# How to make jQuery Up & Down arrow buttons to scroll body vertically step by step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a single page website with 5 sections one below another on a single page.
I need two buttons, Up & Down arrows near scroll bar to help users scroll using these buttons.
These buttons should sequentially scroll to previous & next section respectively.
Basically we are scrolling the whole body.

For example, navigation is lie Home, About, Projects, Gallery & Contact.

When on Home, and clicked Down arrow, body should scroll to About and stop. If on About, the Up button should bring us to the Home section.

I'm a jQuery n00b so, kindly help me with code examples.

Code so far:

```
<div id="arrows">
<a href="javascript:;" id="arrow-up">&uarr;</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="arrow-down">&darr;</a>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The jQuery's (relatively) easy, but how do you define your 'sections'? Can you show representative mark-up for the whole page? Provide a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with? Have you attempted *anything* yet? We're happy to help, but doing it *for* you is a little beyond the Stack Overflow remit.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the jquery animate function:

```
<div id="HomeSection">
   <h2>Home</h2>
   <input type="button" onclick="scollWin('AboutSection');" value="Scroll to Next" />     
</div>

<div id="AboutSection">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>About your page....</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="scollWin('HomeSection');" value="Scroll to Previous" />
    <input type="button" onclick="scollWin('ProjectSection');" value="Scroll to Next" />
 </div>
```

Jquery:

```
function scrollWin(id){
   $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + id ).offset().top
   }, 2000);
}
```

Source and demonstration: [link](http://blog.freelancer-id.com/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery/)